# .NET - Can you change a process's parameters after process start?

Tags: .net, powershell, winapi

The ultimate goal is to change PowerShell.exe's process parameter to set EnableRaisingEvents to $true so that I can trap the exit event if/when my script is terminated.

All of the examples I can find are of setting the properties on a new process object first and then programmticaly spawning it with the start method but I'd like to know if I can just modify the existing process to accomplish this?   ... like an inline update?

If it's possible in .NET, easy but if I need to drop down to WinAPI with p/invoke, I can figure that out too if anyone knows the library/function.  Thx.

Comment: The answer provides a solution to your problem, not an answer to your question. This is largely because you didn't ask for what you need, but rather about your proposed solution. That is a valid reason to down-vote a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnableRaisingEvents` is a property of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance, not the actual underlying operating system process, you can easily modify it regardless of whether the underlying process is already running:

```
$process = Start-Process notepad -PassThru

# Change EnableRaisingEvents flag after process start
$process.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Now the Process instance can raise the Exited event
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process -EventName Exited -SourceIdentifier notepadExited -Action {
    Write-Host "Notepad exited" -ForegroundColor Red
}
$process.Kill()
```

---

If you need to monitor an already running process that you didn't start yourself, you can use the `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` WMI event class:

```
# Using Start-Process for this example, but could be any existing process
$process = Start-Process notepad -PassThru

# Use the query to filter events raised based on process ID
$eventQuery = "SELECT ProcessName,ExitStatus FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessId = $($process.Id)"

# Register WMI Event listener
Register-WmiEvent -Query $eventQuery -Action {
    $traceEvent = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent
    Write-Host "$($traceEvent.ProcessName) exited with status code: $($traceEvent.ExitStatus)"
} -SourceIdentifier notepadExited
$process.Kill()
```